# Tkinter scatter plot

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a GUI application using tkinter where the user is asked to input the x and y values, and when finished, click a button that generates a scatter plot. When I run the code nothing happens, I get no error messages, no window pops up, and I'm not sure what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *

class mclass:
    mylist = []
    mylist1 = []

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.box1 = Entry(window)
        self.button1 = Button(window, text="enter", command=lambda:     get_data1(mylist), width=5)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.box1.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.box2 = Entry(window)
        self.button2 = Button(window, text="enter", command=lambda: get_data2(mylist1), width=5)
        self.button2.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.box2.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        self.box3 = Entry(window)
        self.button3 = Button(window, text="Finish & Plot", command=self.plot)
        self.box3.pack()
        self.button3.pack()


        def get_data1(l):
            l.append(self.box1.get())
            print(l)

        def get_data2(l1):
            l1.append(self.box2.get())
            print(l1)

        var1 = StringVar()
        var1.set("X Values:")
        label1 = Label(window, textvariable=var1, height=2)
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)


       ID1 = StringVar()
       self.box1 = Entry(window, bd=4, textvariable=ID1)
       self.box1.grid(row=0, column=1)

       var2 = StringVar()
       var2.set("Y Values:")
       label2 = Label(window, textvariable=var2, height=2)
       label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

       ID2 = StringVar()
       self.box2 = Entry(window, bd=4, textvariable=ID2)
       self.box2.grid(row=1, column=1)


    def plot(self):
        x = np.array(mylist)
        v = np.array(mylist1)

        fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        a = fig.add_subplot(111)
        a.scatter(v, x, color='red')


        a.set_title ("Scatter Plot)", fontsize=16)
        a.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)
        a.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.window)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        canvas.draw()

window = Tk()
start = mclass(window)
window.mainloop()
```

If anyone could help me on what my error is I would greatly appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly lots of stuff was incorrect in your orignal example and i got plenty of error messages. Most of them were that you used pack and grid together which is not possible within one frame. Here is a working version of your code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *

class mclass:

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.mylist = []
        self.mylist1 = []

        self.window = window

        self.button3 = Button(window, text="Finish & Plot", command=self.plot)
        self.button3.pack()

        var1 = StringVar()
        var1.set("X Values:")
        label1 = Label(window, textvariable=var1, height=2)
        label1.pack()


        ID1 = StringVar()
        self.box1 = Entry(window, bd=4, textvariable=ID1)
        self.box1.pack()

        var2 = StringVar()
        var2.set("Y Values:")
        label2 = Label(window, textvariable=var2, height=2)
        label2.pack()

        ID2 = StringVar()
        self.box2 = Entry(window, bd=4, textvariable=ID2)
        self.box2.pack()

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        self.a = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.window)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    def read_inputs(self):
        x_input = self.box1.get()
        y_input = self.box2.get()


        def convert_to_float_list(x_in):
            x_input_list = x_in.split(',')
            x_floats = [float(x) for x in x_input_list]
            return x_floats


        x_array = np.array(convert_to_float_list(x_input))
        y_array = np.array(convert_to_float_list(y_input))

        return x_array,y_array


    def plot(self):
        self.a.cla()
        x,v = self.read_inputs()
        self.a.scatter(x, v, color='red')

        self.a.set_title ("Scatter Plot)", fontsize=16)
        self.a.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)
        self.a.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)

        self.canvas.draw()

window = Tk()
start = mclass(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Things I did:

- I changed all .grid calls to .pack
- I removed the unnecessary entries.
- I moved the definition of the figure into the init method so that
  not multiple figures are generated
- i removed the all button but the finish&plot one. The values are read before plotting
- the inputs are strings and must be converted to list of floats (or np.arrays) before plotting. The code now assumes comma seperated floats as inputs in x and y entry

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate it!!